# Can one known use of a name be regarded as a nickname?

Tags: naming

On Margaret's Death Registration, Francis is recorded in the 'If married, to whom" section.

The informant section is Frank - Husband. There is no mistaking the 'k' for 'cis'.

The original record is not available.

Other than this document, I have found no record (so far) for Francis with Frank as a name.

As well as recording Frank in the Notes/Source for Margaret's death, should I also list Frank as a nickname?

Comment: There's no hard and fast answer to this -- if you're recording all name variants, you might choose to record this -- but if you though it was a mistake you might annotate the source instead IMO.

Comment: My understanding is that "Frank" was a diminutive of "Francis" and I've seen people in the early 20th century flip back and forth btw the 2 forms. Assuming you agree that there is no error, then you *might* record "Frank" as an alternative / alias name, rather than as a nickname, depending on whether you and / or your software recognise the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Frank and Francis are the same name; one is from the Old German for "a Frenchman", the other is from the Latin for same, transmitted via Italian. E.G. Withycombe's *Oxford Dictionary of English Christian Names* under Frank says that since about the 16th century, Frank has been "the common abbreviation" of Francis.

If you had a relative named James who signed his name somewhere as Jim, would you bother recording Jim as a nickname? Whatever your answer to that question, do the same with Francis/Frank.